# Performance of Python list comprehension: rebuilding lambda in `if` part?

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension

While comparing various equivalent forms of `filter(xs, lambda x: x != el)` in Python, I stumbled upon something that surprised me. Consider the following forms:

```
def method1(xs, el):
    p = lambda x: x != el
    return [x for x in xs if p(x)]

def method2(xs, el):
    return [x for x in xs if (lambda y: y != el)(x)]
```

I would expect that Python'd build the lambda only once, and then store it in a temporary variable, so that both forms perform about as well. Maybe even that `method1` would perform worse due to the name lookup.

But when I benchmarked them, it turned out that `method2` performed consistently worse than `method1`. Why is this? Is it rebuilding the lambda for every iteration?

---

My benchmark script (in a separate module, and expects `methods` to contain `method1` and `method2`) is as follows:

```
import math, timeit

def bench(n,rho,z):
    pre = """\
import random
from methods import %(method)s

x = [(random.randint(0,%(domain)i)) for r in xrange(%(size)i)]
el = x[0]\
"""

    def testMethod(m):
        mod = pre % { 'method': m, 'domain': int(math.ceil(n / rho)), 'size': n }
        return timeit.timeit("%s(x, el)" % m, mod, number = z)/(z * n)

    print "Testing", n, rho, z
    return tuple(testMethod(m) for m in ("method1", "method2"))

n = 31

min_size, max_size = 10.0**1, 10.0**4
size_base = math.pow(max_size / min_size, 1.0/(n-1))
# size_default = 10**3

#min_sel, max_sel = 0.001, 1.0
#sel_base = math.pow(max_sel / min_sel, 1.0/(n-1))
sel_default = 0.001

tests = [bench(int(min_size*size_base**x), sel_default, 100) for x in xrange(n)]
#tests = [bench(size_default, min_sel*sel_base**x, 100) for x in xrange(n)]

def median(x):
    x = list(sorted(x))
    mi = int(len(x)/2)
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return x[mi]
    else:
        return (x[mi] + x[mi+1])/2

def madAndMedian(x):
    meh = median(x)
    return meh, median([abs(xx - meh) for xx in x])

for z in zip(*tests):
    print madAndMedian(z)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is rebuilding the lambda on every loop; it needs to reevaluate that whole expression.

To see this, use the [`dis` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html):

```
>>> dis.dis(method1)
  2           0 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (el)
              3 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <lambda> at 0x102000230, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              9 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             12 STORE_FAST               2 (p)

  3          15 BUILD_LIST               0
             18 LOAD_FAST                0 (xs)
             21 GET_ITER            
        >>   22 FOR_ITER                24 (to 49)
             25 STORE_FAST               3 (x)
             28 LOAD_FAST                2 (p)
             31 LOAD_FAST                3 (x)
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             37 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       22
             40 LOAD_FAST                3 (x)
             43 LIST_APPEND              2
             46 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           22
        >>   49 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(method2)
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (xs)
              6 GET_ITER            
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                33 (to 43)
             10 STORE_FAST               2 (x)
             13 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (el)
             16 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             19 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <lambda> at 0x101fd37b0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
             22 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             25 LOAD_FAST                2 (x)
             28 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             31 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        7
             34 LOAD_FAST                2 (x)
             37 LIST_APPEND              2
             40 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   43 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `LOAD_CONST` opcode loads the compiled code for the lambda body; `MAKE_CLOSURE` creates the lambda from that. For `method1` this happens once, while for `method2` this is repeated in each iteration of the loop (from the `FOR_ITER` opcode to the `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` opcode); note the `LOAD_FAST` opcode for the variable `p` in `method1` where it refers to the local variable instead.

Comment: You're practically tied for time with @cmh, but thanks for the fast answer! :D Do you mind if I give the +15 to the one with least rep?

Comment: @Tinctorius: It's your accept flag, give it to whomever *you* feel deserves it most! :-)

Comment: And then you sneakily make your answer a *little* more precise. I'm onto you! ;)

Comment: @Tinctorius: I *always* try to make my answers just that little better, as I think of more details to add. Sorry!

Comment: @Tinctorius, I would suggest accepting this answer and I'll delete mine. Having a duplicate (but slightly inferior) answer around isn't making the internet a better place.

Answer (score 2):

Python builds the *code* of the lambda only once. But it builds a new *function* object (that refers to the code and the enclosing environment that includes the `el` variable) in each pass of the loop. This would normally be a feature, as each function object could have different properties assigned to it via `__setitem__`.

In this case the function object is not stored anywhere nor leaked outside the scope, so it would be safe to move its the creation outside the loop, but Python's compiler is not yet smart enough to perform such an optimization.

Comment: For a lambda it builds a closure, which is not quite the same as a function. :-) But yes, it only compiles once, but the closure building does take some time. As for 'smart enough'; the dynamic nature of the language makes it *really* hard to do such optimizations safely; PyPy does show that a lot more could be done than what CPython does now though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unlike some other languages, Python doesn't really distinguish functions and closures on the data type level. Functions and closures created from Python are both represented by the `function` data type, whose `func_closure` attributes defines the cells captured by the closure (or `None`/`NULL` if nothing is closed over).

Comment: The bytecode for functions and lambdas differs; functions are loaded with `MAKE_FUNCTION`, lambdas with `LOAD_CLOSURE` followed by `MAKE_CLOSURE`. That's all I wanted to point out. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, the bytecode to create a function must include information on what part of the lexical environment to capture, if any. The resulting function objects are, however, of the exact same type. The distinction between `MAKE_FUNCTION` and `MAKE_CLOSURE` appears to be an artifact of history from the times when Python didn't have closures (and possibly a useful optimization for the simple function case).

Comment: And yes, both those bytecodes (`MAKE_CLOSURE` and `MAKE_FUNCION`) result in a `function()` instance. It's just the way the bytecode is handled needs to differ, because a lambda only supports a simple expression.